# Java interface concept

Tags: java, interface

When you build and interface, how many classes can implement the interface?
If the answer is more than one, then how does java know which implementations to use when you make the call to the interface(not calling the implementation directly)?

Comment: You tell Java which implementation it should use!

Comment: When you use `import` you tell Java which implementation to use.

Comment: An unlimited number can implement the interface, and by specifying a concrete type when you set a reference.

Comment: You could have just made an interface and extended it two times and tried it.

Answer (score 0):

> how many classes can implement the interface?

As many as you need.

> If the answer is more than one, then how does java know which implementations to use when you make the call to the interface(not calling the implementation directly)?

Here helps knowledge about [late binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding) (also known as dynamic binding).

Lets say that you have interface and classes which implement it like

```
interface Animal{
    void makeSound();
}

class Cat implements Animal{
    public void makeSound(){
        System.out.println("mew");
    }
}

class Dog implements Animal{
    public void makeSound(){
        System.out.println("woof");
    }
}
```

You also have code like

```
Animal a1 = new Cat();
Animal a2 = new Dog();

a1.makeSound();
a2.makeSound();
```

Result which you will see is

```
mew
woof
```

It happens because *body/code* of method `.makeSound()` is being looked for (and invoked) *at runtime* (not compilation time). It is possible because each object remembers its class, so object held by `a1` reference knows that it is instance of `Cat` and object held by `a2` is instance of `Dog`.

So in short when you do:

```
a1.makeSound();
```

- JVM takes object which `a1` holds,
- then asks that object about its class (in this case it will learn that it is instance of `Cat` class),
- then it will accesses that class (`Cat.class` file) and is searching for code of `makeSound()` (if such method will not be found, then it will assume it must been inherited it will try to search it in superclass)
- and when it will find this method it will invoke code from it.

Comment: Very well said.  Thank you.

Comment: @MarkoRocko You are welcome. I forgot to add that thanks to this mechanism we have polymorphism in Java. Also there are 3 exceptions from dynamic binding when you are calling `.someMethod()`. First exception when code is set at compilation time and is not searched dynamically at runtime is when method is `final` (since it can't be overridden so there is no point in *searching* it at runtime). Second case is when method is `private` (since private methods are accessed only within class which declares and accessing private methods from other classes is impossible).

Comment: @MarkoRocko Third case is when method is `static` because `reference.staticMethod()` is at compilation time changed into `ReferenceType.staticMethod()`.